# Regex for one word in sentence

Tags: regex, coffeescript

So I am trying to match a (any) word(s) that would have:

1. At least one upper case letter
2. At least one lower case letter
3. At least one number

I currently got to this using lookaheads

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$
```

But I am not able to get this to match on one word. I tried to use `\b` around the lookaheads but it doesn't work. The thing the word that I am trying to match on can have the above conditions in any order. Example: aB5 OR Ba5 OR 5Ba etc.. Need some pointers.

Comment: I am using it in coffeescript. But that said, the basic idea of how to do it wouldn't be language specific right?

Comment: are you sure you want to use single regex, and not something like a sequence of filters?  that is, filter out all words without [A-Z], then all words w/o [a-z], then all words w/o [0-9]?

Comment: noMAD, Regular expressions are surprisingly language (or rather, implementation) sensitive.  I commonly use [This chart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) to see which features are available in the tool/language I'm using.

Comment: @squadette I have never used a sequence filter and I think for my use case a regex should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that `.` includes spaces. You need to change your `.`'s to be restricted to word-characters only, i.e. `\w`. Note that `\w` is (mostly) `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, if you wish to exclude some of these or include more, you should make the appropriate changes.

Another thing is that if you're looking for words in a string, you need to remove `^` and `$` because these mean the start and end of the string respectively.

Since all your requirements are "at least" (as opposed to "at most"), you don't really need `\b` because of matching happens left-to-right, so you can never get part of a word.

Regex:

```
(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])\w+
```

[Test](http://www.rubular.com/r/oHuy7J26I4).

Answer (score 2):

> I currently got to this using lookaheads
>
> ```
> ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$
> ```
>
> But I am not able to get this to match on one word.

Lookaheads are the correct approach, but if you want to find single words only you must not allow every character (`.`) in between but only word-characters (like `\w`). So

```
/(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=.\w[A-Z])\w+/g
```

should do it. Of course you're free to allow more letters than only `\w`, maybe even `\S`.